# How to get a specific field of the data to use it in a request?

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I am building an app with Polymer and Go at the moment and i just went into this problem.

I have my data stored in a MongoDB, and I am using JWT for the authentication.
The data I will use here is User { email, ...} and the invitation {sender , receiver, event, message , ...}

The problem is : i made a new functionality and I need for my HTTP Request to put the user's Email as an argument but i get the error Can't get 'Email' of Undefined from the google console.

to do so i have 2 polymer components 
1 - a component to get the "Invitation" (message, sender, event)
2 - a component that uses the (1) and is just a repeater to show all the invitations a user receives.

I tried to make use another component to get the current user's Email and it didn't work as well, same problem the this.me.Email doesnt work (see in the code below)

(1) the ['collab-service'].me(this.token) returns into the property 'me' the user's data so i have access to me.Email (what i need here)

```
 static get properties() {
            return {
                invitation: {
                    type: Object,
                    notify: true,
                },
                /**
                 * Current user
                 * @public
                 * @type {Object}
                 **/
                me: {
                    type: Object,
                    notify: true,
                    reflectToAttribute: true,
                },
            };
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         **/
        connectedCallback() {
            super.connectedCallback();
            this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');

            this.$['collab-service'].me(this.token).then(
                (request) => {
                    this.me = request.response;
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.error('Error.');
                    console.error(error);
                }
            );
```

(2) GetInvitation(User's email) returns all the invitations received by the User

```
<div class="container">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{invitation}}" as="item">
                    <MyComponent1 pub="{{item}}"></MyComponent1>
                </template>
            </div>

{......}
 static get is() {
            return 'myFile2';
        }

        static get properties() {
            return{
            };
        }
        connectedCallback() {
            super.connectedCallback();
            this.$['invitations-service'].getInvitations(this.me.Email).then(
                (request) => {
                    this.invitation = request.response;
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.error('Error.');
                    console.error(error);
                }
            );
        }
```

So what i need is to make this.me.Email work so that i can see every invitation.
I put the an element {{me.Email}} into the HTML code to see if i had something in the "me" property and 'me.Email' exists. It returns the current user's email. It just doesnt work in the method getInvitation and i don't know why.

Thank you for the help !

EDIT :I changed to code, added a  to load the invitations and it has access to the this.me.Email attribute...
It fixes the problem for now but it's really not elegant.
I think it is due to the loading of the me property, i use it when it's not loaded already, so when the page is loaded i have access to the me attributes but not as i load it.

Comment: Honestly, to be able to give you a good enough answer, I need to know the full structure of the HTML page(s), not just tidbits of code.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have reflectToAttribute on the `me` property? reflectToAttribute just for the DOM so you can add attributes to the element, like `hidden` or `name="MyElement"`, often used to style the element.

```
hidden: {
  type: Boolean,
  value: true,
  reflectToAttribute: true
},
name: {
  type: String,
  value: 'MyElement',
  reflectToAttribute: true
},
```

In the DOM, the element above would look something like `<my-element hidden name="MyElement">`.

---

`notify: true` is used to send variable updates from a child element to a parent element.

```
<parent-element>
  <child-element child-data={{parentVariable}}></child-element>
</parent-element>
```

Placing the property withing curly brackets `{{}}` tells parent-element that updated data can come from the child-element.

```
static get is() {
            return 'parent-element';
        }

        static get properties() {
            return{
               parentVariable: Object
            };
        }
```

Parent element isn't sending in anything to its child in this example.

```
static get is() {
            return 'child-element';
        }

        static get properties() {
            return{ 
              childData: {
                type: Object,
                notify: true
              }
            };
        }

        ready() {
          super.ready();

          this.set('childData', {'test': 'hello world'});
        }
```

Because child-element has `notify: true` on `childData`, setting that property will now update `parentVariable` in parent-element to the same value.

---

If you want anything to update in DOM or in your properties, you need to use `this.set('myVariable', aValue)` and not `this.myVariable = aValue`.

---

It seems like you're wanting asynchronous data in `connectedCallback`, but you can't be sure that it's loaded. Sure, it's loaded afterwards when you try to see if the property is there. It seems like you figured that out by the look of your edited update, but you should probably set up a two-way binding of properties, instead of querySelect elements and then place an observer to see when the element has updated.

If I continue the example above:

```
static get is() {
            return 'parentElement';
        }

        static get properties() {
            return{
               parentVariable: {
                 type: Object,
                 observer: 'testObserver'
            };
        }

        testObserver(newChildData) {
          console.log(newChildData); // {'test': 'hello world'}

          // do other stuff, like getInvitations(newChildData.test)
        }
```